# PHP solution for Epaper

Tags: php

I am working on a news paper website which has epaper facility. I am developing it in php. 
Is there any script or something else where I can learn how to make an epaper site.

I want solution like this http://epaper.timesofindia.com/Default/Client.asp?Daily=TOIM&showST=true&login=default&pub=TOI&Enter=true&Skin=TOINEW&AW=1333084145015

Please help me out..

Comment: "epaper" is not a generally-recognized term, except when applied to [display technologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper). Please restate your question.

Comment: I believe he is looking for an extremely specific tutorial on how to build the exact website he is trying to build.

Comment: ePaper is a reader webapp, it looks a lot like that awful one that always comes up when I'm searching for something spec-y on google.  I hate web readers. Just an embarrassing attempt by some publishers to cling to the print-media model.

Answer (score 2):

ePaper in your context is a web app developed by [Pressmart](http://www.pressmart.com), and it appears to be proprietary, or at the very least not developer-friendly. So I highly doubt there have been advances in PHP libraries for it.

I'm sure as a partner, they have internal documentation and tech support that you can request more information from. They may even have a web API with PHP examples (I've seen worse companies that knew they had to keep up).

This is all info I've gathered in the last 7 minutes, so there may be more out there.  But you should  always reach out to the developer support of the product if they don't have easy access to documentation, as this is a sure-sign that there is not a large population of developers in the general community that will know what you're talking about, let along give insight.